# How is @NonNull or @Nullable function?

Tags: android

like :

```
public TestBean check(@NonNull TestBean abc) {
    System.out.println();
    return abc;
}
```

`@NonNull` api doc say:

> Denotes that a parameter, field or method return value can never be null

I have a question: if abc is null, why it executes this method?

Comment: please improve ur question, no one can understand what you are asking

Comment: I guess these annotations are only useful for your IDE to warn you of potentially null pointer errors.

Answer (score 1):

These annotations may used by code analysis tools (and IDEs) and documentation. They aren't enforced by the runtime.

An example is given here in the android support kit documentation: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

The new [Android Studio](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/googles-gift-android-studio) supports these annotations, screenshot in the link.

Java 8 introduced similar annotations and [this documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_s_new_type) goes into a little more detail about how these annotations work with tools and IDEs to help developers detect problems earlier. In plain Java, you can use the [Bean Validation API](http://beanvalidation.org/) to enforce null checking declaratively at runtime, I don't know if there's any similar capability in Android.

Comment: code analysis tools？What is the purpose？and no NullPointException tip in eclipse IDE。

Comment: To warn the developer when a variable that's never supposed to be null will be null based on code analysis. Different IDEs support different capabilities and annotations. If you have a look at the link I posted, you'll see if explained in more detail, I think you need a plugin that's part of the Android support kit to get support in Eclipse (from reading the site I linked)

Comment: Thanks，i use android studio is usefull，Thank you for your answer again

Answer (score 0):

They just make it more easier to check underlying NULL point exception in your code time.